# VB.NET array of forms

Tags: arrays, vb.net, forms

Suppose I have three Forms:  Form0, Form1, and Form2.
EACH of the forms contains two Textboxes:  Tb0 and Tb1.

There's nothing else in any of the forms.  The forms differ only in the actual text in each of the textboxes (and, of course, the "names" of the individual forms).

The Forms are contained in an array named FORMS -- i.e.,

```
  FORMS = {Form0,Form1,Form2}
```

I would like to access (for reading and writing) the first textbox (Tb0) in Form1.  I expect to be able to do that via

```
 StringVariable = FORMS(1).Tb0.text   or    FORMS(1).Tb0.text = "some string"
```

but no variations of the above approach produces anything but errors.  Two days of "google search" have been fruitless.  Suggestions??

Comment: `produces anything but errors`  Always helpful if you tell us the errors.

Comment: Are `Form0`, `Form1`, and `Form2` classes or instances? If they are classes, then you are using the default instances and that is one of two things wrong with your code, the second being that you should create a base form with the control Tb0, or a user control. But you should use OOP somewhere, so you don't need to search for the control. The question, and accepted answer, should not be taken as the right way to do this sort of thing. Perhaps these are in fact only `Form` and are created dynamically then `Controls.Find` is fine-ish, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure the `TextBox` items are public visible with [`Modifiers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-the-modifiers-and-generatemember-properties) property so you can access the `TextBox` items from outside of the forms.

> By default, the Windows Forms Designer assigns the `private` (`Friend` in Visual Basic) modifier to container controls like `Panel`.

Now you can access (read and write) the `TextBox` like the following:

```
Dim FORMS() As Form = {Form0, Form1, Form2}

'read the value
Dim StringVariable As String = FORMS(1).Tb0.Text

'write the value
FORMS(1).Tb0.Text = "some string"
```

---

**Another (and more flexible) solution:**

With the following solution you can get and set the value of a `TextBox` item also in case the `Modifiers` is set to `Private`. The solution is also more flexible in case the `TextBox` item is not available on the `Form`.

```
'set all the forms to an array.
Dim forms() As Form = {Form1, Form2, Form3}

'search for a specific control on the first form of the array.
Dim foundControls() As Control = forms(0).Controls.Find("TextBox1", True)

'check if the control is available and a TextBox.
If foundControls.Length = 1 AndAlso TypeOf foundControls(0) Is TextBox Then
    Dim txtControl As TextBox = DirectCast(foundControls(0), TextBox)

    'set a value to the TextBox.
    txtControl.Text = "Hello"

    'get the value from the TextBox.
    Debug.Print(txtControl.Text)
End If

'... or using the functions (much easier to use).
SetTextBoxValue(forms(0), "TextBox1", "Hello World")
Dim strValue As String = GetTextBoxValue(forms(0), "TextBox1")
```

You can use functions to easier set and get the values of the `TextBox` items:

```
Private Sub SetTextBoxValue(ByVal frm As Form, ByVal txtName As String, ByVal txtValue As String)

    'search for a specific control on the first form of the array.
    Dim foundControls() As Control = frm.Controls.Find(txtName, True)

    'check if the control is available and a TextBox.
    If foundControls.Length = 1 AndAlso TypeOf foundControls(0) Is TextBox Then
        Dim txtControl As TextBox = DirectCast(foundControls(0), TextBox)
        txtControl.Text = txtValue
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetTextBoxValue(ByVal frm As Form, ByVal txtName As String)

    'search for a specific control on the first form of the array.
    Dim foundControls() As Control = frm.Controls.Find(txtName, True)

    'check if the control is available and a TextBox.
    If foundControls.Length = 1 AndAlso TypeOf foundControls(0) Is TextBox Then
        Dim txtControl As TextBox = DirectCast(foundControls(0), TextBox)
        Return txtControl.Text
    End If

    Return ""
End Function
```

Comment: `Dim FORMS() As Form = {Form0, Form1, Form2}` limits the items to Form, which doesn't have Tb0. `Dim FORMS = {Form0, Form1, Form2}` should work.

Comment: In my many iterations, I THINK (!!!!!) I tried that without success.  In any case, the solution offered by Mr. Brosch fixed me.  Yay!

Comment: @djv I can't get `Dim FORMS = {Form0, Form1, Form2}` to work (assuming I have those forms in the project). Option Strict doesn't want to infer Object. 'Dim FORMS() As Form = {Form0, Form1, Form2}' works as expected.

Comment: With this answer, you won't get any errors during design time if `Form1` doesn't contain an object `Tb0` but during runtime an error pops up.